# how to know if app is in background or foreground when push notification is received using IBM Mobilefirst

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a Android Native App which is integrated with IBM MobileFirst SDK.

My requirement is I receive a Push Notification when app is in foreground I need to show a dialog in the UI. But when App is in Background and receives a Push notification in the notification drawer of the phone and I click on it It should open the app but should not show any Dialog.

How do I differentiate these two cases because the call back that is happening on these both cases is **onMessage(String props, final String payload)**?

So I am unable tell wether the notification reached notification drawer or directly to the app.

I am using MobileFirst 7.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to track your app visibility state by yourself. Easiest way to do this is to implement Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks and detect your Activity state.

Comment: OK. But I was wondering if Ibm Mobilefirst SDK has some solution to this? Like if it has any call back which tells this message is from notification rack.

Comment: This is not part of MFP SDK out of the box. This will have to be a custom solution.